# Python SqlAlchemy | Issue on CSV bulk insert in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm beginner of "**Python** with **sqlAlchemy**".

I try to insert my bulk **CSV** data's to **MySQL** by using the following,

**My Code :**

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('/home/shankar/LAB/Python/company_bi.csv')
# 2nd argument replaces where conditions is False
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None) 
df.head()
conn_str = "mysql+pymysql://root:*****@localhost/globalTracker?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0"

engine = create_engine(conn_str)

conn = engine.raw_connection()

df.to_sql(name='company', con=conn, 
      if_exists='append',
      chunksize=10000, dtype=object,
      index_label='SOS_VOTERID')
conn.close()
```

NOTE : In Some cases, another **CSV** files are working, but some of them not imported properly due to Encoding issues. 
Even tried "dtype" as "mysql", also i get the same.

**Error I Got :**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0c08d4874fc0> in <module>()
 12           if_exists='append',
 13           chunksize=10000, dtype=object,
---> 14           index_label='SOS_VOTERID')
 15 conn.close()

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
 1163         sql.to_sql(self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema,
 1164                    if_exists=if_exists, index=index, index_label=index_label,
 -> 1165                    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
 1166 
 1167     def to_pickle(self, path):

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
 569     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
 570                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
 --> 571                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
 572 
 573 

 /home/shankar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
 1651         """
 1652         if dtype is not None:
 -> 1653             for col, my_type in dtype.items():
 1654                 if not isinstance(my_type, str):
 1655                     raise ValueError('%s (%s) not a string' % (

 AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'items'
```

Kindly Notify my Bug ...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `dtype` is supposed to be a "dict of column name to SQL type", not `object`.

Comment: So what can i do for Raw CSV insert into MySQL ?

Comment: Well, your question was about the bug you had when you specified `dtype=object`, which is simply due to an incorrect argument. If your question is really about "encoding issues" then you should elaborate on what those issues are. As it stands, the code is fine for inserting rows from a CSV.